# What to gitignore from firebase from GitHub repository

Tags: android, firebase, github, repository, gitignore

I'm adding firebase to my mobile app.
I'm wondering what I should include and ignore from my GitHub repository?

I ignored everything from the Android.gitignore here:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/

However firebase adds the following folder:
Is there anything I should put in my repository from this folder?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing you should exclude is the `google-services.json` file.

Comment: Really? Why would you include libraries which you can update from google?
Also if you look at that gitignore file, theres a lot more than the google-services.json

Comment: where is the gitignore for firebase in the link you posted in question? I could not find one